# PHP - output form text as .txt file using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have a textarea, text input and a button wich sends textarea and text input values (using AJAX post method) to PHP site.
Now, I want PHP to output textarea value as .txt file so that user can download what he wrote in textarea.

My PHP code looks like this:

```
$text=trim($_POST['text']);  // textarea value
$fileName=$_POST['fileName'].".txt";  // text input value
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
header("Content-Length: ".mb_strlen($text));
print($text);
```

Nothing happens, so can you help me please.
Thanks.  :)

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? The form which processes, what does AJAX have to do with it?

Comment: Try to add "exit;" after the print.

Comment: @Typoheads That does not matter.

Comment: You are telling your browser that it should use AJAX to obtain the response but you send back text/html, with content-disposition: attachmenton top of it. This is the same as asking why Jupiter can't use knife and fork for all that matters. TL;DR: you can't do it that way. Read what @RichardBernards wrote as answer.

Comment: @RichardBernards You are right. I didn't see that it is an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't load the code via AJAX, but via a normal request.

In your case, the easiest way to achieve this, is to add a target to the form you are using to post the data like so:

```
<form method="post" action="script.php" target="_blank"> 
    %%_inputelements_and_submitbutton_%%
</form>
```

Comment: and how can i do that?

Comment: Instead of loading it via AJAX, just make it a regular link (`<a href="script.php">asdf</a>`)

Comment: ok, but i want that user can do that at any time not losing the text that he wrote (link would redirect him to sript.php site)

Comment: set the target on `_blank` for the link like so: `<a href="script.php" target="_blank">download</a>` and this will not happen

Comment: thanks but it hast to be more elegant way to do that, i mean, you can't transfer data with simple link, it has to be a form or ajax request am i right?

Comment: What you can do, is add the target to the form element and do away with the AJAX request: `<form method="post" action="script.php" target="_blank"> %%_inputelements_and_submitbutton_%% </form>`; You'll keep the elegant way of transmitting data, and make sure you'll get a download instead of a new pageload. If you setup the php-script properly (looks ok, but test it to be sure), there should not be an empty tab loaded, but just the browser-dialog handling the download.

Comment: @Crle I have updated the answer with the sample code of the form. If this is the solution to your problem, please mark it as the answer.